# Updating Person Field javascript error

Tags: 2013, javascript, client-object-model, person

I am creating a new list item using CSOM. When I try updating a Person field, I'm getting a error saying my function is undefined

> Uncaught ReferenceError: createListItem is not defined

it happens with the introduction of this line:

```
SP.User _newUser = clientContext.Web.EnsureUser("domain\\user");
```

Isn't this part of Sp.js? I have this imported along with sp.core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var theUser = context.get_web().ensureUser("DEV\testowner");
context.load(theUser);

context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
    //Create list item here
},
function(sender, args){
  alert(args.get_message());
});
```

Comment: perfect! I just needed to add an extra backslash and it worked thanks Amal.
("DEV\\testowner")